# Customize buttons in App Bar for each component with React

Tags: reactjs

I have a set of components where I want each of them to display an AppBar that I have defined as follows:

```
const FireAppBar = (props) => {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          {props.route &&
            <Link to={{ pathname: props.route }} style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
              <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="contrast">
                <ArrowBackIcon/>
              </IconButton>
            </Link>}
          <Typography type="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
            {props.title || ''}
          </Typography>
          {props.rightIcon
            ? props.rightIcon
            : <Avatar className={classes.orangeAvatar}>M</Avatar>}
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to customize the App Bar look based on the Component that's being rendered. I.e. if a `route prop` is being passed, I want to render a Back button.

The way I currently do this is by specifically including the AppBar in each of my components such as:

```
class Entries extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      entries: [],
      jobId: ''
    };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AppBar title={`Entries for ${this.state.jobId}`} route={"/jobs"}/>
        <EntriesTable entries={this.state.entries}/>
        <Link to={{ pathname: `/createEntry/${this.jobKey}` }}>
          <Button fab color="primary" aria-label="add" className={classes.button}>
            <AddIcon />
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Is there any way to just include the App Bar in the top level App.js component instead of specifying it in each component?

```
class App extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   console.log(nextProps.location)
  }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <main>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Jobs} />
            <Route path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
            <Route path="/entries/:id" component={Entries} />
            <Route path="/createEntry/:id" component={CreateEntry} />
          </main>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(App);
```

Comment: why not render it as a sibling to the root `App` component?

Comment: How would I customize the buttons in the app bar in that case?

Comment: via `props` the same way you are doing now

Comment: But the app bar would be a parent component. How would I pass props to the parent component?

Comment: parent to the router?!

Comment: I added my App.js in the description above as well. Ideally I would have my AppBar in the App.js file instead in each of the components below. However, I'm not sure how I could pass components up if I define the AppBar in the parent component